# Hand shake failure exception for ignite in EKS

Tags: ignite

I am trying to deploy apache ignite 2.15.0 docker image in EKS. I am getting following exception:

```
[07:39:26,843][SEVERE][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries) [maxTimeout=0]
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:81)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2057)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1992)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1283)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:1120)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:472)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2206)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:277)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:1075)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1764)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1151)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1725)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1647)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1089)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:983)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:889)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:808)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:678)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:647)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:325)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:365)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.kubernetes.connection.KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.getServiceAddresses(KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.java:123)
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:76)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:318)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:185)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:197)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1572)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1500)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.kubernetes.connection.KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.getServiceAddresses(KubernetesServiceAddressResolver.java:111)
```

can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

I am not using ssl for ignite in EKS. How to solve this issue.

Comment: The SSL error is when Ignite tries to connect to the Kubernetes API. It's difficult to say much more than that with the information provided.

Comment: @StephenDarlington Could you please guide to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which Ignite image are you using? What version of Kubernetes? (`kubectl version`)

Comment: I am using apacheignite/ignite:2.15.0 image and 1.27 kubernetes version. I am using kubernetes ip finder. This image working fine in docker . Issue is in kubernetes

Comment: It's going to be something like the ciphers in JDK 8 are not new enough for the way Amazon have configured the Kubernetes API. Try using the JDK 11 image (apacheignite/ignite:2.15.0-jdk11) instead of the regular one.

Comment: Thanks @StephenDarlington it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to ignite image. apacheignite/ignite:2.15.0-jdk11 image worked fine in K8s 1.27. Thanks to @StephenDarlington.

Comment: To be clear, this is not an issue with Ignite or Kubernetes 1.27. It's the way that Amazon has configured some of its security settings.